# postgresQL foregin Key Insert

Tags: postgresql

```
                 with ins as (
                    insert into upload_file (
                        uf_name, 
                        uf_hash, 
                        uf_width, 
                        uf_height, 
                        uf_ext,
                        uf_mime,
                        uf_size, 
                        uf_path, 
                        uf_type 
                    )
                    values %L
                    returning uf_idx
                )
                insert into upload_file_formats (
                    ud_file_formats,
                    uf_idx
                ) select v.formats, ins.uf_idx
                from (
                    values %L
                ) v(formats)
```

Hello, I am doing bulk insert with nodejs pg-format module now. There is a forgein key table, so I am inserting with cte. I need to join. Can I get uf_idx from SQL and insert uf_idx into the forgein key table? let me know if there is a way

Comment: What is "*a foreign key table*"? What do you want to insert there? What do you need to join?

Comment: foregin key table is upload_file_formats and The insert data is uf_idx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `ins` to the `FROM` clause of the `SELECT` of the second `INSERT`, perhaps like

```
FROM ins CROSS JOIN (values %L) v(formats)
```

Comment: When a cross join is performed, the same data is inserted multiple times.

Comment: Yes. If there is more than one row, use a different join. The fact remains that you must have `ins` somewhere in there.